# Retrieve value from interpolated function

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am very new to python, and as a project I decided to write my Mathematica project in python to see how it works, hence the code is written in as close a style to Mathematica as possible.

I am struggling to call a value from an interpolated function, in a simple working example I want to do this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

a = np.linspace(1,10,10)
b = np.sin(a)
inter = interp1d(a,b)

# this is where i get a value from the interpolated function
s0 = inter(a[0])
print(s0)
```

This is my MWE that does not work:

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import *
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

E0 = -0.015
L = 5.5
Ns = 1000


# this solves for where the energy E0 intersects the potential y
def req(E0):
    L=5.5
    r = Symbol('r')
    y = -(2*L**2)/(r**3)+(L**2)/(r**2)-(2)/(r)
    rr = (E0-y)*(r**4)
    rreq = Eq(rr, 0)
    rrt = sorted(solve(rr), key=int)
    return rrt 

# upper and lower limits on r
r1 = req(E0)[1]
r0 = req(E0)[2]

# initialise the arrays
a = np.array([1])
b = np.array([1])

# numerically integrate the function R(r)
for n in range(2, Ns):
    # integrate 
    lwlmt = r0
    uplmt = r0+(n-1)*(r1-r0)/(Ns-1)

    result, error = integrate.quad(lambda ra: -1/((E0-(-(2*L**2)/(ra**3)+(L**2)/(ra**2)-(2)/(ra)))*(ra**4))**(0.5), r0, uplmt)

    a = np.append([uplmt],[[a]])
    b = np.append([result],[[b]])

# chop the 1 from the end
aa = a[:-1]
ba = b[:-1]

# interpolate
inter = interp1d(aa,ba)

# this is the problem
print(inter(110))

# this is what i would ideally like to do,
# get the start and end points however i receive an error
s0 = inter(aa[0])
s1 = inter(aa[len(aa)-1])


plt.plot(aa,inter(aa))
plt.show()
```

Strangely my MWE only works if I use the entire array as an argument `inter(aa)` it returns a list of interpolated points.
I can't work out why the first example works, while the second one doesn't. Both arrays appear to be the same, however only the first example actually produces an output.

EDIT: adding the error returned

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/nick/Documents/python/<ipython-input-4-b36b3f397c2e> in <module>()
     45 # this is what i would ideally like to do,

     46 # get the start and end points

---> 47 s0 = inter(aa[1])
     48 s1 = inter(aa[len(aa)-1])
     49 

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.pyc in __call__(self, x_new)
    364         # from y_new and insert them where self.axis was in the list of axes.

    365         nx = x_new.ndim
--> 366         ny = y_new.ndim
    367 
    368         # 6. Fill any values that were out of bounds with fill_value.


AttributeError: 'Float' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

This is the error for any number I put in the val argument `inter([val])`, that is in the range of `aa`.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific for 'does not work': produces wrong results, gives an error (what is the traceback) etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `req()` is a sympy object rather than a real Python float, and thus, `uplmt` is also a sympy object. numpy's numerical routines do not know what to do with these sympy objects. Convert to Python float objects early.

On my machine, the values of `r0` and `r1` are actually complex, just with tiny imaginary components, and they cause an error earlier than the one you show. It's easy to convert them, though:

```
# upper and lower limits on r
r1 = complex(req(E0)[1]).real
r0 = complex(req(E0)[2]).real
```

After I make that change, your script executes to completion for me, though I cannot guarantee that it is giving you your desired numerical result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this has done exactly what I want/